# Sometimes entity framework inserts multiple "parent" row after adding "children" to a new (parent) element

Tags: c#, entity-framework, npgsql

I'm trying to figure out what could cause the entity multiplication in case of adding children to it (one-to-many connection).

My code is very complex, the classes have much more properties but the main problem is the following.

Here is a sample code:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Parent()
    {
        Children = new List<Child>();
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
}
```

The **child can live without the parent so does the Parent**.

So when I want to connect two entities it have to work fine in the code. It's not possible to create a new Parent entity if there is one already. **The process is linear.**

For example I create **three child** first without a parent (this is the 1st state) and **saving it to the Db**.
Then I "process" the entities (maybe a day after creating the children):

- Selecting the **first Child and creating a Parent if couldn't find one by it's name** (children are already in the DB).
- Adding **child** to the parent't Children List.
- Saving the dbContext.
- Looping while I have any child who has no parent.

Code example:

```
public void ProcessChildren()
{
    IDbContextTransaction trans = dbContext.BeginTransaction();
    foreach(var item in Children) //Children is a list of child entities (existing in the DB)
    {
        var parent = dbContext.Parents.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == item.ParentName);
        if(parent == null)
        {
            parent = new Parent{Name = item.ParentName};
            dbContext.Parents.Add(parent);
        }
        parent.Children.Add(item);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    trans.Commit(); //rollback implemented if it fails
}
```

What I have then (only sometimes and very rarely) is **3 parents and 3 child witch don't have ParentIds**, so it looks like (for me) that the EF is crashed in some way and did this accidentally.

So this bug happens during a huge process (from few hundred thousand children there were created few ten thousand parent) and the chance of the bug showing up is still very low (not really intentionally reproducible). However in my system it causes a consequences.

Have anyone heard of a behavior like this? Maybe the problem is with EF (EntityFramework 6.2.0 Nuget) or the Npgsql extension (EntityFramework6.Npgsql 3.1.1 Nuget) of it?

**EDIT:** Adding code example of saving and creating entities.
**Edit2:** Parent null reference exception fix.
Sorry the code is written here it's an example of the way it works, not the code itself.

Comment: You will need to add the where you are are assigning the newly created parent to the child records (in a minimal way)

Comment: @TheGeneral Added an example of what I thought of.

Answer (score 0):

After this line, you just add new Parent in a database context, but your "parent" variable doesn't change and it will stay null.

```
if(parent == null)
{
    dbContext.Parents.Add(new Parent{Name = item.ParentName});
}
```

So every time parent will be null, you'r code will be crashed when you want to access to the null variable here `parent.Children.Add(item);`

You can try to assign the parent variable to the newly added parent object.

```
if (parent == null)
{
    parent = dbContext.Parents.Add(new Parent{Name = item.ParentName});
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you right, thanks. I corrected it here. That can't be the issue cause in the "real code" it is created the right way. Other way i would get **NullReferenceException** and the whole process would roll back.